# Better way to set up samba bridge?

Tags: networking, samba, network-bridge

I have an old ubuntu laptop hooked up to between my wireless network and a wired media player box.

I had previously shared my wireless network connection so the media player had internet access  (ie. via nat) because it was a different subnet it could not access the file shares on the wireless network. To get around this I mounted the drives from the wireless network on the laptop and re-shared them with samba.

This worked ok but had some drawbacks, it seemed slow and if network computers were turned off when the laptop rebooted I had to manually mount the shares.

I've just re-installed with the latest ubuntu and was wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Is there some way to bridge so the media player appears to be on the wireless network? Would this give better performance? Any other options? I'm also thinking there might be some samba options that could buffer files?

Edit:
To bridge multiple interfaces I believe you can do something like:

```
brctl addbr br0
brctl addif eth0
brctl addif eth1
```

then you configure the address of br0

this gives the error: "Operation not supported". According to [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/howto-bridge-wireless-and-wired-network-interfaces-369455/) post it is not simple to bridge wired and wireless networks.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 1):

GUI tool to create network bridges:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/bridger/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.